# dynamic controls with c# being overwritten

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am attempting to add some dynamic form elements to my asp page using c# whenever a button is clicked.  The code is working, but it is overwriting itself as opposed to placing the panel, label and textbox generated in one click after the elements generated in the previous click.  The counter is controlled by a global variable.  I am probably missing something very simple, but any help would be great.
Thanks!

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Panel pnl = new Panel();
    pnl.ID = "Panel" + count.ToString();
    Panel1.Controls.Add(pnl);

    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.ID = "Textbox" + count.ToString();
    pnl.Controls.Add(tb);

    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.ID = "Label" + count.ToString();
    lbl.Text = "Label" + count.ToString();
    pnl.Controls.Add(lbl);
    count++;

}
```

You can see the effect here:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screen shot (or at least a link to a screen shot) of what you are seeing?

Comment: Thanks Chris, here's a link: http://mechanical-legs.com/samples/cs_screen.jpg.  Circled is the label form element that is updated with each button click.

Comment: I assume there should be text box and label next to "Step 3"

Comment: "step 1", "step 2" and "Step 3" are links that the the form wizard added.  Sorry.  I should have simplified the asp before posting.  I uploaded a simpler screenshot in the same location with just the form fields, labels and button.

Comment: Try making Panel1.Controls.Add(pnl); the last call.

Comment: Well, the elements are still being over written even if I add the panel as the last call.  I sorta solved the issue using javascript.  Though I am will continue to troubleshoot this particular c# solution.  I think it would be very valuable to generate form elements by way of the code behind.

Answer (score 1):

Each time the button is clicked, you get a postback. On subsequent load of the page, asp.net has no memory of the previous controls you added in the event handler. You would need to track this yourself - in viewstate - and recreate previously added controls in the page's Init event by interrogating viewstate before the next postback is processed. If you don't recreate them in Init, they will not function correctly (e.g. they won't be able to postback themselves or otherwise contribute to the page's event lifecycle.)

Here's some more information:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1186195.aspx/1